# TargetNamespace in CXF simple frontEnd

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am using CXF simple frontend that uses XML configs only stead of annotations for creating soap web services.

Now I have created a service:

```
<simple:server id="locationSettingService"
        serviceClass="com.my.own.webservice"
        address="/LocationSettingWebService">
        <simple:serviceBean>
            <bean
                class="com.my.own.webserviceImpl">

            </bean>
        </simple:serviceBean>
        <simple:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="addressingHandler" />
            <ref bean="authHandler" />
        </simple:inInterceptors>
        <simple:dataBinding>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding" />
        </simple:dataBinding>
    </simple:server>
```

After its deployment wsdl is:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="LocationSettingWebService" ... targetNamespace="http://own.my.com/">
```

It uses targetNamespace `http://own.my.com/`

My problem is I dont want forward-slash at the end of above namespace I only need `http://own.my.com` as my targetNamespace .So I want to modify the namespace using simple frontend. Any help?

Update:
 After searching for a long time and trying a hundreds of workaround. I figured out the problem, CXF namespace generation technique is '/' ahead of XFire had.

Go to [this page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/aegis-databinding-20x.html) .And look for XFire compatibility but I tried many things but got no luck escaping that '/'. Please help people I even opened up bounty from my little SO reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to work this out, Thanks to apache's mailing list and it's very generous people.

All I needed is to add  FactoryBean with very first configuration being `XFireCompatibilityServiceConfiguration` because it's a rule first who returns configuration wins.

```
  <simple:server id="locationSettingService"
        serviceClass="com.my.own.webservice"
        address="/LocationSettingWebService">
<simple:serviceFactory>
            <ref bean="aegisCompatibilityFactoryBean"/>
        </simple:serviceFactory>
        <simple:serviceBean>
            <bean
                class="com.my.own.webserviceImpl">

            </bean>
        </simple:serviceBean>
        <simple:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="addressingHandler" />
            <ref bean="authHandler" />
        </simple:inInterceptors>
        <simple:dataBinding>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding" />
        </simple:dataBinding>
    </simple:server>
```

and that factory bean itself

```
<bean id="aegisCompatibilityFactoryBean"
        class="org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
        <property name="serviceConfigurations">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.XFireCompatibilityServiceConfiguration">
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.service.factory.DefaultServiceConfiguration" />

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And make sure the scope of this bean is prototype if you are using it for multiple web services.